# How to use ListBoxes?

Tags: c#, windows

I'm a beginner to programming Windows applications in C#, so I do not understand basic controls.

Lets say I am writing a program in which you select a number in a ListBox, and a MessageBox is displayed with that number. How would I associate each item in the list to an event?

Thank you very much. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: WPF or Windows Forms?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/96df2c84-3507-4322-a441-4c3ba2a6522b/how-to-get-multiple-selected-values-and-items-from-listbox-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show a message box, you have to set an `SelectionChanged` event:

```
listBox.SelectionChanged += (sender, args) => MessageBox.Show(listBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

or simplier for beginner:

```
listBox.SelectionChanged += ShowMessageBox;

private void ShowMessageBox(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(listBox.SelectedItem.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ListBox stores several text items. It can interact with other controls, including Button controls. We use this control in Windows Forms. In the example program it interacts with two Buttons—through the Button Click event handler.

List _items = new List(); // <-- Add this

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    _items.Add("One"); // <-- Add these
    _items.Add("Two");
    _items.Add("Three");

    listBox1.DataSource = _items;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is Winforms,you can access the **listbox Selected value changed** event.A sample code would be like

```
     private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(((System.Windows.Forms.ListBox) (sender)).SelectedItem.ToString());
    }
```